# External Drive Encrypted Journaled - Show Password Hint

Tags: hard-drive, password, external-disk, encryption

I encrypted an external hard drive using MacOS Journaled Encrypted about a year ago. I'm confident that I was prompted to provide a password hint when I entered the original password and formatted the drive.

Now, when I connect the drive on a new computer running MacOS Sierra, I cannot get the password hint to show. Online pictures show a button on previous UIs but not on the current UI.

I contacted Apple and they sent the question to the engineers. They got back to me and said the engineers were aware of it, and it would be fixed in a future update.

I'm wondering if anyone here knows of another way to expose the password hint, maybe using a PC (doubtful) or Terminal. I'd like to access the hard drive and do not remember the password but am confident that the hint would help me.

Comment: There are password programs that store passwords - not that they will help you with this one but for the future.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. I am confident that the hint is stored in the hard drive and there is a way to show it, but I haven't found it yet. I summarized my progress and asked about it here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444615/find-and-decode-bytes-containing-passphrase-hint-cryptousers-structure-in-file